# Laravel cannot connect to MySQL in Amazon RDS, but can connect from command line

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am working on Laravel project hosted on AWS EC2(Ubuntu) with RDS(MySQL) on the same VPC.
I can connect to MySQL through command line with no problem, but when Laravel app tries to connect to database, the access is denied.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'username'@'ipaddress' (using password: Y   ES) (SQL: select * from
>   `tablename`)

Below is my DB config in .env file:

```
DB_HOST=verylonghostname.rds.amazonaws.com  
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=dbname   
DB_USERNAME=dbusername 
DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword
```

What might be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: When you say you can connect through the commandline is this when you SSH to the EC2 server? Is it using the same username and password as Laravel tries to? Also can you query from the database Laravel tries to when you connect in the commandline?

Comment: If larvel did a `SELECT CURRENT_USER()`  would the host part of that answer include the IP address range you are connecting from?

Comment: @apokryfos yes I ssh to ec2 server then connect to rds with the same user and passwd as in laravel env file. I can also make query to the same database with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried create another db user for laravel and it works!
Apparently the connection is denied if I use db user name 'admin'. 
Perhaps it is one of security measure by AWS.

Comment: I have same problem. I have installed phpmyadmin on same ec2 instance and I am able to connect via dbuser/dbpass to my RDS instance. However I am having SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'ec2-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = myemail@domainame.tld limit 1) when trying to connect via Laravel Application. Clearly it is trying to connect to local instance rather than the RDS instance. Any idea?

Comment: Also I am able to connect to DB when I use ssh to ec2 instance server

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, i.e. I was able to connect to the database through dBeaver as well as through a php file contained in the /var/www/html folder. However, it would not connect through Laravel app. The issue got fixed after I enclosed the password within quotes in the ".env" file.

```
  DB_PASSWORD='xyz#xxxccc'
```